# SuiteScript afterSubmit execution Order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to update a field on save that requires a value from another field in the record. That field gets set by another script that also runs on afterSubmit for the same record. My script is not able to pick up the set field value.

Is there any option to define the order in which afterSubmit scripts are run?

Or, alternative, delay the execution by a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to Customization > Scripting > Scripted Records, locate the record type you are scripting. Editing the Scripted Records page for that record type, you will be able to reorder the scripts and workflows running on the record type.